# How to update 3rd party module without taking the site down

Tags: magento2.4.3, third-party-module

Is there a way to update a module without taking the server down or have any downtime?

We have a few websites where we can't really have any downtime until late at night, so updating modules is a pain. Can this be done without taking the server down?

I have Magento 2.4.3 cloud